# What is the difference between try/except and assert?

Tags: python-3.x

```
try:
def function_addition(x,y):
    assert (y!=0)
    total= x/y
    return total
num1=float(input("Write a number :"))
num2=float (input("Write a second number:"))
result=function_addition(num1,num2)
assert (num2 !=0)
print (result)
```

except AssertionError:
    print ("Error!Check your inputs")

I wrote the code above ,but I don't know why I got the same result when I do: `except ZeroDivisionError: 
So can I delete assert and replace it by except ZeroDivisionError ?`

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert` only check if a condition is true or not and throw an exception. A `try/except` block can run a few statements and check if any of them throw an exception so you can process it in the `except` part. Examples:

```
assert(1 == 2)
```

will give you an `AsertionError`.

```
try:
    # some statements
    # ...
except OSError as err:
    #If an OSerror exception is thrown, you can process it here. For example:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
```

Your code will look like this:

```
def function_addition(x,y):
    try:
        assert (y!=0)
    except:
        raise ValueError('y is 0.')
    total= x/y
    return total


num1=float(input("Write a number :"))
num2=float (input("Write a second number:"))
try:
    result=function_addition(num1,num2)
except ValueError as ve:
    print(ve)
else:
    print(result)
```

If you save it in a *fun.py* file and run it, you will have this output:

```
Write a number :1
Write a second number:2
0.5
# Run it again.
Write a number :0
Write a second number:0
y is 0.
```